# I can't set labels in Django forms fields

Tags: python, django, forms

This is my model:

```
class CalEvents(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    activity_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, unique=False, blank=True)
    activity_type = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=False, blank=True)
    activity_code = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=False, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Activity: '{}' - @{}".format(self.activity_name, self.user.username)
```

This is my forms.py (with my attempted solutions to define the labels):

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from gCalData.models import CalEvents
from accounts.models import User


class CalEventsForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CalEvents
        fields = ['activity_name','activity_type','activity_code']
        labels = {"actiity_name": "Activity name",
                    "activity_type": "Activity type",
                    "activity_code": "Activity code"}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CalEventsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['activity_name'].label = "Activity name"
        self.fields['activity_type'].label = "Activity type"
        self.fields['activity_code'].label = "Activity code"
```

This is the part of my template where I put the form:

```
<tr>
  <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
  {% for field in form %}
    <td>{{ field }}</td>
  {% endfor %}
  <td><input type="submit" name="new_record" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Activity"></td>
  </form>
</tr>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't seem to be outputting any labels in your template. And why are you defining them twice in the form class?

Comment: You're technically setting the labels up correctly i'm pretty sure but Django only automagically displays labels when you render the form all together instead of individual fields. Replace your `for` loop with `{{form}}` and you should see your labels. [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#working-with-form-templates) for reference.

Comment: It was just to show what I had attempted so far. How should I output them? Shouldn't they come out of {{ field }}?

Comment: If you want to manually control where the fields and labels appear, you'll need `{{field.label_tag}}` in your `for` loop for the label instead of just `{{field}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `{{ field.label_tag }}` (the html wrapping you decide):

```
{% for field in form %}
   {{ field.label_tag }}
    <td>{{ field }}</td>
  {% endfor %}
```

**Edit**

You may also add the error tags:

```
{% for error in field.errors %}
 <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">{{ error|escape }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```